# How can I open a PDF to a certain page from within excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, macros

I would like a macro code for Excel 2013 that will open up a certain page upon clicking a button in the excel cell. I am using the below code, but it is working intermittently. Please help with a proper code.

```
Sub q8()
Dim IE As Object, strFile As String, iPageNum As Long
strFile = "C:\Users\Neanderthal\Desktop\Maths Practice\GMAT OG 13_2015.pdf"
iPageNum = 19
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate strFile & "#Page=" & iPageNum
IE.Visible = True
End Sub
```

As of now, the IE is opening up with the PDF file but opens up with the first page in focus. But I want the 19th page to show.

How can I do this? The solution does not have to be a macro. Any which way, I could open a PDF with a certain page from within an excel shall do.

Comment: This may help http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2012/07/vba-macro-to-open-pdf-file.html